# wrong color channels, pygame cairo rsvg drawing

Tags: pygame, cairo, pycairo, rsvg

I have cairo+rsvg rendering a .svg file in pygame. But the color channels are wrong.

testing with [lion.svg](http://croczilla.com/bits_and_pieces/svg/samples/lion/lion.svg)

But image is:
[image]

I believe I have my RGBA channel order swapped, (He's pink, not yellow). but am not clear on how it works. Here's my code, (which otherwise is rendering right.)

Maybe `pygame.display.set_mode(...)` or `pygame.image.frombuffer(...)` is the relevant problem?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import * 
import os
import cairo
import rsvg
import array

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 60,60

class Lion(object):
    """load+draw lion.svg"""
    def __init__(self, file=None):
        """create surface"""
        #  Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.screen = pygame.display.get_surface()                                    
        self.image = None
        self.filename = 'lion.svg'
        self.width, self.height = WIDTH, HEIGHT

    def draw_svg(self):
        """draw .svg to pygame Surface"""
        svg = rsvg.Handle(file= os.path.join('data', self.filename))        
        dim = svg.get_dimension_data()
        self.width , self.height = dim[0], dim[1]

        data = array.array('c', chr(0) * self.width * self.height * 4 )
        cairo_surf= cairo.ImageSurface.create_for_data( data,
            cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, self.width, self.height, self.width * 4 )
        ctx = cairo.Context(cairo_surf)

        svg.render_cairo(ctx)
        self.image = pygame.image.frombuffer(data.tostring(), (self.width,self.height), "ARGB")

    def draw(self):
        """draw to screen"""
        if self.image is None: self.draw_svg()
        self.screen.blit(self.image, Rect(200,200,0,0))

class GameMain(object):
    """game Main entry point. handles intialization of game and graphics, as well as game loop"""    
    done = False
    color_bg = Color('black') # or also: Color(50,50,50) , or: Color('#fefefe')

    def __init__(self, width=800, height=600):
        pygame.init()

        self.width, self.height = width, height
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(( self.width, self.height ))
        #  self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(( self.width, self.height ),0,32) # 32bpp for format 0x00rrggbb

        # fps clock, limits max fps
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.limit_fps = True
        self.fps_max = 40

        self.lion = Lion()

    def main_loop(self):
        while not self.done:
            # get input            
            self.handle_events()
            self.draw()
            # cap FPS if: limit_fps == True
            if self.limit_fps: self.clock.tick( self.fps_max )
            else: self.clock.tick()

    def draw(self):
        """draw screen"""
        self.screen.fill( self.color_bg )
        self.lion.draw()
        pygame.display.flip()

    def handle_events(self):
        """handle events: keyboard, mouse, etc."""
        events = pygame.event.get()

        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: self.done = True
            # event: keydown
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE: self.done = True

if __name__ == "__main__":         
    print """Keys:
    ESC    = quit
"""    
    game = GameMain()
    game.main_loop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed - the byte order for each channel is different from cairo to pygame.
You can either juggle with the array before converting it to a string, to post the data in the correct order for pygame (you'd have to swap the green and blue data for each pixel) - or use
an aditional dependency: Python's PIL, to properly handle the different data at native speeds.

There is an snippet for that in pygame's site:

```
def bgra_surf_to_rgba_string(cairo_surface):
    # We use PIL to do this
    img = Image.frombuffer(
        'RGBA', (cairo_surface.get_width(),
                 cairo_surface.get_height()),
        cairo_surface.get_data(), 'raw', 'BGRA', 0, 1)
    return img.tostring('raw', 'RGBA', 0, 1)

 ...
 # On little-endian machines (and perhaps big-endian, who knows?),
# Cairo's ARGB format becomes a BGRA format. PyGame does not accept
# BGRA, but it does accept RGBA, which is why we have to convert the
# surface data. You can check what endian-type you have by printing
# out sys.byteorder
data_string = bgra_surf_to_rgba_string(cairo_surface)

# Create PyGame surface
pygame_surface = pygame.image.frombuffer(
    data_string, (width, height), 'RGBA')
```

Check the whole recipe at: http://www.pygame.org/wiki/CairoPygame

If you don't want to add an aditional dependence (PIL in this case), Python's native arrays allows slice assignment - with those it is possible to swap the data of your blue and green channels at native speeds - try this swapping (may need some tunning :-)  this is what worked for me after loading your image above as a png file, not from  a cairo context )

```
def draw_svg(self):
    """draw .svg to pygame Surface"""
    svg = rsvg.Handle(file= os.path.join('data', self.filename))        
    dim = svg.get_dimension_data()
    self.width , self.height = dim[0], dim[1]

    data = array.array('c', chr(0) * self.width * self.height * 4 )
    cairo_surf= cairo.ImageSurface.create_for_data( data,
        cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, self.width, self.height, self.width * 4 )
    ctx = cairo.Context(cairo_surf)

    blue = data[1::4]
    green = data[3::4]
    data[1::4] = green
    data[3::4] = blue
    svg.render_cairo(ctx)
    self.image = pygame.image.frombuffer(data.tostring(), (self.width,self.height), "ARGB")
```

Comment: 1] I ran your non-PIL solution. But it does nothing different, if I toggle the slices block on/off. (I didn't save as a .png as an intermediate step.)2] Would `blue = data[1::4]` reference the red, since it's in ARGB? Unless I'm misunderstanding it.

Answer (score 1):

If the array slicing is not working, may I offer the PIL approach?

It was inspired by the same [Pygame recipe](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/CairoPygame) jsbueno mentioned, but I cleaned it up and organized to a self-contained function. It takes a filename as argument, and return a `pygame.Surface` just like `pygame.image.load()` would.

```py
import pygame     # python-pygame
import rsvg       # python-rsvg
import cairo      # python-cairo
import PIL.Image  # python-imaging

def load_svg(filename):
    ''' Load an SVG file and return a pygame.Surface '''

    def bgra_rgba(surface):
        ''' Convert a Cairo surface in BGRA format to a RBGA string '''
        img = PIL.Image.frombuffer(
            'RGBA', (surface.get_width(), surface.get_height()),
            surface.get_data(), 'raw', 'BGRA', 0, 1)
        return img.tostring('raw', 'RGBA', 0, 1)

    svg = rsvg.Handle(filename)
    width, height = svg.props.width, svg.props.height

    surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height)
    svg.render_cairo(cairo.Context(surface))

    return pygame.image.frombuffer(bgra_rgba(surface), (width,height), "RGBA")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use PIL, the correct array slicing is:

```
def draw_svg(self):
    """draw .svg to pygame Surface"""
    svg = rsvg.Handle(file= os.path.join('data', self.filename))        
    dim = svg.get_dimension_data()
    self.width , self.height = dim[0], dim[1]

    data = array.array('c', chr(0) * self.width * self.height * 4 )
    cairo_surf= cairo.ImageSurface.create_for_data( data,
        cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, self.width, self.height, self.width * 4 )
    ctx = cairo.Context(cairo_surf)
    svg.render_cairo(ctx)

    blue = data[0::4]
    red = data[2::4]
    data[0::4] = red
    data[2::4] = blue

    self.image = pygame.image.frombuffer(data.tostring(), (self.width,self.height), "ARGB")
```

Comment: Hi @Simon Lopez. Welcome to SO. Thanks for your answer. By the way, can you add some more details about what you changed and why, please?

Comment: Hi @GustavoStraube, I've fixed the color swapping. The previous answer was not using the good indexes.